# How does one perform testing with a SAML 2.0 controller?

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, saml-2.0, itfoxtec-identity-saml2

I have a .Net 5 Entity Framework project that I have added the ITfoxtec SAML 2.0 library to it.

I need to be able to connect to a corporate network that uses SAML 2.0. The IT guys say I need to "create a SAML 2.0 assertion to point the the corporate SAML route."

I followed the code examples on the Git Repository and added all the needed configuration elements to my `startup.cs` class.

Also in my `AuthController.cs` I have added the following:

```
   [Route("Login")]
   public IActionResult Login(string returnUrl = null)
   {
        var binding = new Saml2RedirectBinding();
        binding.SetRelayStateQuery(new Dictionary<string, string> { { relayStateReturnUrl, returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/") } });

        return binding.Bind(new Saml2AuthnRequest(config)).ToActionResult();
   }

   [Route("AssertionConsumerService")]
   public async Task<IActionResult> AssertionConsumerService()
   {
        var binding = new Saml2PostBinding();
        var saml2AuthnResponse = new Saml2AuthnResponse(config);

        binding.ReadSamlResponse(Request.ToGenericHttpRequest(), saml2AuthnResponse);
        if (saml2AuthnResponse.Status != Saml2StatusCodes.Success)
        {
             throw new AuthenticationException($"SAML Response status: {saml2AuthnResponse.Status}");
        }
        binding.Unbind(Request.ToGenericHttpRequest(), saml2AuthnResponse);
        await saml2AuthnResponse.CreateSession(HttpContext, claimsTransform: (claimsPrincipal) => ClaimsTransform.Transform(claimsPrincipal));

        var relayStateQuery = binding.GetRelayStateQuery();
        var returnUrl = relayStateQuery.ContainsKey(relayStateReturnUrl) ? relayStateQuery[relayStateReturnUrl] : Url.Content("~/");
        return Redirect(returnUrl);
 }
```

The project builds and runs, but I'm not sure how to test this ITfoxtec SAML 2.0 library.

Does anyone have any experience with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply test it by opening the browser and clicking login. The ITfoxtec Identity SAML 2.0 component will with your code do a redirect to your corporate IdP and it expects a post back through the browser.

Comment: Thanks! Are the corporate IdP endpoints typically just a controller URL?  Also,  my .Net Core SP app would need a GET method to connect to the IdP endpoint and a POST method to receive the IdP answer? Thanks again!

Comment: The corporate IdP usually espose a metadata endpoint which describes the endpoints. Your .NET Core SP app would send a GET, not receive it. Your .NET Core SP app needs a POST endpoint to receive the IdP response.